# Passing Objects in IPC using Messenger in Android

Tags: android, ipc, messenger

I am using Messenger instead of aidl in Android for IPC. I have a service with which clients can bind . **How can i pass a custom object form service to a client using Messenger Mechanism for IPC** so that client can use that object to invoke operations.I know we can send simple data types using Parcelable or databundle but what about custom objects

Comment: Let custom objects implement `Parcelable` like in http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

Answer (score 1):

> How can i pass a custom object form service to a client using Messenger Mechanism for IPC so that client can use that object to invoke operations.

You can't. Apps in one process cannot hold objects from another process, let alone "invoke operations" upon them.

Comment: i want to send callbacks to service just as we do using aidl should i use simple messaging for callbacks and pass parameters for callback using bundle

Comment: @cdka: If you wish to use `Messenger` for IPC, you will need to limit yourself to data types that can go into a `Bundle`.

Comment: Thanks so that is the limitation of using Messenger instead of aidl i guess.