# How to pass an origin object(NOT COPY) from one activity to another on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, parameter-passing

How to pass origin object from one activity to another on Android?

For sure, we can serialized (Serializable, Parcelable, to/from JSON) and pass a copy of the object's data and a new object having the same data could be created; but it will NOT have the same references.

Here is some solution:

Code for the first activity:

```
final Object objSent = new Object();
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBinder(OBJECT_KEY, new ObjectWrapperForBinder(objSent));
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class).putExtras(bundle));
```

Code for the second activity:

```
final Object objReceived = ((ObjectWrapperForBinder)getIntent().getExtras().getBinder(OBJECT_KEY)).getData();
```

but the minimum API Level required **18**

Are there other ways?

Comment: What you wanted to achieve by 'passing' the original object to another activity? Can a global class holds that object and retrieve from another activity works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
[BundleCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/BundleCompat.html) allows to use putBinder/getBinder for all Android versions.

ActivityA:

```
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
BundleCompat.putBinder(bundle,KEY, new ObjectWrapperForBinder(callback));
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

ActivityB:

```
object = ((ObjectWrapperForBinder)BundleCompat.getBinder(intent.getExtras(),KEY)).getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your goals.
If you're going to work inside one process, you can just simply use `Singleton` pattern.
But if you want to pass your real object to, for example `Service`, which has attribute `android:isolatedProcess="true"` :

```
<service
    android:name=".service.SomeService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:isolatedProcess="true"/>
```

Then you can't pass your origin object to another process.

> You can't. Apps in one process cannot hold objects from another
>   process, let alone "invoke operations" upon them.

Source: [Passing Objects in IPC using Messenger in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599410/passing-objects-in-ipc-using-messenger-in-android)

So, as I can see you are're trying to pass your origin object using `Intent` mechanism. In my opinion, it's impossible to do it through the `Intent`'s, because `Bundle`, which contained in `Intent` doesn't store references to real objects. So, it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In such case,[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) will be a great choice.It's something like global Subscribe-Observer and it can help to pass origin object between any objects.

Do this in the activity where you want to pass an object:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

Do this in the activity where you want to receive the object:

First,register the activity:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

Second,define an method with @Subscriber to receive the object:

```
@Subscribe
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event)
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -2):

Sample object should be Parcelable.

```
SampleObject objSent=new SampleObject();
Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(objSent);
startActivity(intent);
```